# Xcode: unable to open configuration settings file

Tags: ios, xcode

I upgraded to macOS Ventura using Xcode 14.1 and I'm now getting this build error:

[image]

iOS deployment target is 16.0 and project format is Xcode 14.0 compatible. I'm using cocoapods 1.11.3 for package management.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out you have to go to Project > Info > Configuration and change the following:

[image]

Comment: there isn't any "Configuration" on xcode on monterrey. any other idiea?

Comment: It the left column in xcode switch form "targets" to "project", you will find configuration in info. Did not worked for me though